# Botorch equality_constraints argument example in the optimize_acqf function

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm doing a Bayesian Optimization code with [BoTorch](https://botorch.org/v/0.2.3/) and I want to apply a constraint like x2+x4+x6=1 to the candidates, so I use the optimize_acqf function with this signature:

```py
 new_x, value = optimize_acqf(
        acq_function=acq_func,
        bounds=to.tensor([[0.0] * 20, [1.0] * 20]),
        q=BATCH_SIZE,
        num_restarts=10,
        raw_samples=100,  # used for intialization heuristic
        options={"batch_limit": 5, "maxiter": 200, "nonnegative": True},
        equality_constraints=[(to.tensor([2,4,6]),to.tensor([1,1,1]),1)],
        sequential=True,
    )
```

But when I try to run the code, I get a `RunTimeError (dot : expected both vectors to have same dtype, but found Long and Float)` in the equality_constraints argument (if I comment that part out, the error disappears). I've tried setting the dtype of the tensors to float (as I reckon that the float tensor is the one from the data, and then it gives `ValueError: No feasible point found. Constraint polytope appears empty. Check your constraints.`)

I've searched the docs, and [here](https://botorch.org/v/0.2.3/api/optim.html) it says that the signature of the argument I want is

> constraints (equality) – A list of tuples (indices, coefficients, rhs), with each tuple encoding an inequality constraint of the form sum_i (X[indices[i]] * coefficients[i]) >= rhs

In another [page referring to the same function](https://botorch.org/api/optim.html#botorch.optim.optimize.optimize_acqf) (afaik) It says that the list of tuples should contain tensors and floats

> equality_constraints (List[Tuple[Tensor, Tensor, float]] | None) – A list of tuples (indices, coefficients, rhs), with each tuple encoding an equality constraint of the form sum_i (X[indices[i]] * coefficients[i]) = rhs

From what I understand, the argument performs something like this in the case of the example given, where `equality_constraints=[(to.tensor([2,4,6]),to.tensor([1,1,1]),1)]`

```py
for i in range(num_rows):
    X[i,2]+X[i,4]+X[i,6] = 1
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how I should define those tensors to run correctly.

**Can someone give me a simple example of how to use this argument?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, and a bunch of hours lost tracking code, I've found out that the [optimize_acqf](https://botorch.org/api/optim.html#botorch.optim.optimize.optimize_acqf) makes a call, under the hood, to [gen_candidates_scipy](https://botorch.org/api/generation.html#botorch.generation.gen.gen_candidates_scipy) which, in turn, when `equality_constraints` is given, calls the function [make_scipy_linear_constraints](https://botorch.org/api/optim.html#botorch.optim.parameter_constraints.make_scipy_linear_constraints).

In the docstring of that function (or the docs, it doesn't really matter) we can see a good example of how to use the equality_constraints argument:

> Example:
>
> The following will enforce that `x[1] + 0.5 x[3] >= -0.1` for each `x`
> in both elements of the q-batch, and each of the 3 t-batches:
>
> ```
>     >>> constraints = make_scipy_linear_constraints(
>     >>>     torch.Size([3, 2, 4]),
>     >>>     [(torch.tensor([1, 3]), torch.tensor([1.0, 0.5]), -0.1)],
>     >>> )
> ```
>
> The following will enforce that `x[0, 1] + 0.5 x[1, 3] >= -0.1` where
> x[0, :] is the first element of the q-batch and x[1, :] is the second
> element of the q-batch, for each of the 3 t-batches:
>
> ```
>     >>> constraints = make_scipy_linear_constraints(
>     >>>     torch.size([3, 2, 4])
>     >>>     [(torch.tensor([[0, 1], [1, 3]), torch.tensor([1.0, 0.5]), -0.1)],
>     >>> )
> ```

So, going back to the example in the question:

> From what I understand, the argument performs something like this in the case of the example given, where equality_constraints=[(to.tensor([2,4,6]),to.tensor([1,1,1]),1)]
>
> ```
> for i in range(num_rows):
>    X[i,2]+X[i,4]+X[i,6] = 1
> ```

That understanding is correct, and the function is eliminating the candidates that do not fit that constraint.